# Microsoft SQL Standard 2012 DB recovery without .BAK file?

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore, recovery

Morning, I'm posting for some guidance on an issue we're up against. We had a server crash and don't have .BAK file for our SQL DB (the backup/images failed). Anyhow, we DO have a file level backup of the entire Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER folder.

Is there any hope at being able to piece this SQL instance / DB back together?

Answer (score 2):

If the mdf and ldf files for the database were in that directory, you might be able to get the database up and running again by trying to "attach" the mdf and ldf files into a new SQL Server instance. The answers on these other Stack Overflow / DBA questions go into more detail on exactly how to attempt that:

- [SQL Server: How to attach / repair a detached / damaged database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995380/sql-server-how-to-attach-repair-a-detached-damaged-database)
- [How to attach an .mdf file that was not properly detached?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42762/how-to-attach-an-mdf-file-that-was-not-properly-detached)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any hope at being able to piece this SQL instance / DB back together?

Hope?  Yes.
*Realistic* expectation?  No.

> We had a server crash and don't have .BAK file for our SQL DB (the backup/images failed).

None at all?  OK, if the *last* one failed, that's bad, but if you have none at all?  frankly, that's unforgivable.  (And your Management may think this too.  If it's actually your *job* to make sure that your databases are recoverable, then this could be an "Epic Fail" of *employment-threatening* proportion).

> ... we DO have a file level backup ...

```
Database != Files
```